# How do you turn the word "faith" or "belief" into an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

Behavior: behavioral. 
Devotion: devotional.
Shakespeare: Shakesperean.

Faith?

Belief?

Comment: This really needs context or examples where you might want to use such words as an adjective. I answered below, but it is pretty much a dictionary lookup answer.

Comment: The compounds _faith related_ and _belief related_ would have to suffice. Some logical adjectival forms seem to have been expropriated by worshippers of deities. This is an interesting question at its root, though. +1

Comment: @user3169: "There are three types of evidence: spiritual, "faith ...?" and empirical." How's that for context?

Answer (score 3):

*Faithful* means *having faith* in the sense of "full of" faith, but it does not mean *of faith* or *having to do with faith* like the other words in your example mean.

Probably *X of faith* is the best you can do.

> He took his devotional book ...
>
> He took his book of faith ...

Likewise with *belief*.

Answer (score 2):

> [*faith-based*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/faith-based):
>   *adjective*
>   affiliated with or sponsored by a church or other religious organization.
>   "Let them perform their faith-based magic and put a spell on me-to kill me right here and now." *Terry Goodkind NAKED EMPIRE*

There is also [*faithful*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/faithful) but the meaning is rather broad, so you would have to check it in context.

*belief* really doesn't have an adjective form directly, though you could possibly use [*believable*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/believable). You might even get away with *belief-based* though I couldn't find it in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can say: faithful and reliable

Answer (score 1):

How about "**convictional**" ? As one of the meaning of it is strong belief. However, it's not a very common word.